# Windows web browsers - a definitive list

Tags: windows, browser

I'm looking for some alternatives to the following browsers for Windows:

- [Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/ie)
- [Firefox](http://www.getfirefox.com)
- [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)
- [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari)
- [Opera](http://www.opera.com)

In particular ones that are lightweight, **can display images** and fast like Chrome/Safari 4 or Firefox was pre 1.5 - although it's not a prerequisite. Can anyone feed me a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[K Meleon](http://kmeleon.sourceforge.net/) is pretty lightweight, [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/Overview.html) definitely isn't, and neither's [SeaMonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/)

There's a long list including all the IE wrappers [here](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/browsers_for_windows.php3).

Comment: Exactly what I was after (the IE wrappers but K Meleon looks decent too)

Answer (score 5):

The most lightweight browser I ever heard of is [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_browser) :-)

Comment: Quite valid alternative, though not many windows users will know it :)

Comment: I would use links instead of lynx any day.

Comment: Links (a successor of lynx) has graphics mode - http://links.twibright.com/features.php

Answer (score 1):

If Lynx isn't good enough because of not displaying images, you can still use [Arachne](http://sourceforge.net/projects/arachne-browser/) for DOS (I'm sure it'll work in Windows, too) ;)

**EDIT**: The SourceForge page has no downloads, [here](http://www.glennmcc.org/arachne/) is a download of 1.95 (November 2008) for DOS and 1.93 for Linux.

Comment: I doubt it. Arachne uses its own OSI stack, all the way up from network level, not to mention clever-DOS-memory-tricks. That's not going to fly under Windows (but may work in DOSBox or another VM).

Comment: VM and a FreeDOS image should work, the only problem left could be to find a Network driver, but most VMs give good network access.

Comment: The project has no downloads available

Comment: Damn.. seems the homepage (http://home.arachne.cz/) is down too - but here's a good download link: http://www.glennmcc.org/arachne/

Answer (score 0):

As always, Wikipedia has a [list of web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers). I'm sure you can find something in that gold mine, but [Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser)) is my lightweight browser of choice. :)

List of web browsers supported on Windows: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/browsers_for_windows.php3

Comment: Unfortunately they don't do a windows only page on wikipedia

Comment: Here's a windows list: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/browsers_for_windows.php3

Answer (score 0):

"In particular ones that are lightweight, can display images and fast like Chrome/Safari 4 or Firefox was pre 1.5 - although it's not a prerequisite. Can anyone feed me a list?"

Opera fulfills those criteria, except that it's on your list. Hmmm. No, really: I'm running Opera 9.5 on a 90 MHz Pentium w/ 128 MB RAM and it runs just fine (with Flash and Java switched off, but that's for another flamewar).